# Inline condition doesn't load script reactjs nextjs app

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, typescript, next.js

I have a problem with a inline condition for loading scripts. The conditions works because the  tag shows me de text but for script it doesn't works. How can I solve it.

```
  const cookie = new Cookies().get('cookiesAccepted');

  const [loadScript,setLoadScript]= useState(cookie);

  function cookieAccepted(){
    setLoadScript(true);
  }
return(
{loadScript &&
      <h1>test</h1>
      }
 <Cookie meta={cookieAccepted.bind(this)}/>
      { loadScript && 
       <script 
       async
       src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/"
     />
    
      }
      {loadScript &&
        <script 
        dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
          __html: `
          window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
          function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
          gtag('js', new Date());
          gtag('config', '********', {
            page_path: window.location.pathname,
          });
        `,
        }}
      />
      }
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend using the Script function from next js.

```
import Script from 'next/script';
```

Instead of adding  tag, you could be doing something like this:

```
{cookieAccepted && (
  <Script src={`https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/`}/>
)}
```

Check this link for more references:
https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/script